# Change geomarker in symbol

Tags: openlayers

How is't possible to change the geomarker in another symbol?
For examle 'a bike'

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code of the OL3 example there is a collection of styles, change its style there if you don't want to modify much of the code :

```
'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 0],
        anchorOrigin: 'bottom-left',
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'yourBikeImage.png or whatever supported extension'
    }))
})
```

you can also edit the style of that feature with:

```
geoMarker.setStyle(yourStyle);
```

Comment: what means this error? i received it..

ol-debug.js:3061 Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: imageAnchor must be truthy

Comment: have you checked the path to your bike image ?

Comment: yes , i changed this example with the path of my bike and that works

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html

is it maybe because the bike is an image , downloaded from google?

Comment: there is a similar issue in OL3 https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1676, but I think it is fixed with the last version, what version of OL3 are you using ?

Comment: the last one

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol-debug.js

Comment: try with ol.js instead of ol-debug.js

Comment: doesn't change anything, still error..

Comment: also with this src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/examples/data/icon.png' it gives the error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43127/discussion-between-hicham-zouarhi-and-niels).

Comment: there was a }) missing at the end, I tried the code again and it worked fine

Comment: could you make perhaps a fiddle? :) That would be awesome
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/HichamZouarhi/L5w8hhua/2/ the icons won't load in jsFiddle try it in your browser and it will work